# Stretched QGIS Hexbin in Google maps

Tags: qgis, google-maps, postgis-2.2

I am very new to GIS so please forgive me if the question is naive, but I haven't found a solution yet.

I generated a mock hexbin in QGIS using MMQGIS plugin, with project set to EPSG:4326 and saved to PostGIS.

[image: Expected result]

When queried as Geojson via Postgis, the returned data looks stretched in Google Maps.
[image: End result]

I have tried to save in EPSG:3857 Google Mercator but that doesn't work either.

---

Creating the map in 3857 was the answer, however I did try before without success, however trying via DB Manager did the trick, the Target SRID was the missing piece in the puzzle!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When projecting data from a long/lat system to a Mercator projection, your data will always be stretched by a factor of sec(y) (i.e. [image: f1]) in the vertical direction (derivative of Mercator equations that you can find e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329691/covert-latitude-longitude-point-to-a-pixels-x-y-on-mercator-projection)).

At your latitude (London), the stretching factor will be around 1.6.

Some solutions you could try:

- create your hexagonal grid directly in a Mercator-type projection (EPSG:3857 should be fine)
- stretch your grid by 1/1.6 in the vertical direction (or 1.6 in the horizontal direction) with PostGIS or some other tool (no clue about the way to proceed, though)